# return all records where the completed date is greater than a previous record's next due date?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Ok, so this feels like a complicated query due to a poor design of the database, but alas -- it is there and in need of solving. The table has 5 fields: id(PK), itemNumber(FK), completedDate, completedBy(FK), nextDue.

In the application, when someone records a task as being done, it fills in the completedDate, calculates the next due date and puts that in nextDue.

What I need, is a query that will basically look at a record's nextDue date, then look ahead to the next record that has the same itemNumber, and compare with that completedDate; then return the row if the completedDate exceeds the completedBy date. Does that make sense? Can this be done? It sounds like it would have to be done procedurally vs. pure sql. TIA

UDPATE:
I guess I should be more specific. I need to use this query in a report, so if it needs to be done in VBA, I'm not sure how to get the results into that.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to write the query statement in SQL and save it as an MS Access query object, then base your report on it.

Can you be a little more specific about what you need the query to look for and compare?  I'm not quite following the business case.

For instance, when you say "ahead to the next record with the same itemNumber" do you mean "next" by [id] or next by one of the date fields?

Comment: itemNumber is a field. The item number is a foreign key that refers to a job that needs to be completed. What I need the report to do is read a record, within that record is a field called itemNumber and a field called nextDue. I need it to read the date from the nextDue field, then look for the next record that has the same itemNumber as the first record. When it finds it, it needs to compare the nextDue field from the previous record with the completedDate field from the later record and return it if completedDate is later (or greater) than the nextDue field from the previous record

Comment: Ok sounds good, when you say "next record" though what qualifies a record as the next one?  Just the record with a higher [id] and the same [itemNumber]?

Comment: Also:  Is the original record being passed in as a parameter or should this return all records in the DB that meet this qualification?

Comment: It should be all records that meet this. The expected output would be a list of all records that were completed late, basically. Next record would be basically the higher id and same item number. In this particular case, no records will ever be deleted, so it shouldn't pose a logic problem. I updated my OP to show a visualization of the operation for 1 single instance.

Comment: By the way, I think your database schema is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the best way to think about these weird queries is to break 'em down into smaller manageable queries in my mind.  So, I think about this as first associating and then comparing two records:  The 'current' and the 'next' records.  The first thing we want to do is associate each record (which will become the 'current') with it's corresponding 'next' record.

So, first, a query that gets all records IDs and their corresponding "next record".  This uses a less than "<" in the JOIN statement to get all of the records that are after the current record.

```
SELECT
     T.id as currentId,
     MIN(A.id) as nextId
FROM
     rec_completionDate as T
          JOIN
     rec_completionDate as A ON T.itemNumber = A.itemNumber and T.id < A.id
GROUP BY
     T.id
```

Follow it up with a query that, using the above as a subquery, returns all of the appropriate fields for each record (current and next):

```
SELECT
     current.*,
     next.*
FROM
     ( ... [subquery goes here] ...) sq
          JOIN
     rec_completionDate as current ON sq.currentId = current.id
          JOIN
     rec_completionDate as next ON sq.nextId = next.id
```

Lastly, we'll want to limit the results of that last query with the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
     next.completedDate > current.nextDue
```

So, putting it all together:

```
SELECT
     current.*,
     next.*
FROM
     ( 
     SELECT
          T.id as currentId,
          MIN(A.id) as nextId
     FROM
          rec_completionDate as T
               JOIN
          rec_completionDate as A ON T.itemNumber = A.itemNumber and T.id < A.id
     GROUP BY
          T.id
     ) sq
          JOIN
     rec_completionDate as current ON sq.currentId = current.id
          JOIN
     rec_completionDate as next ON sq.nextId = next.id
WHERE
     next.completedDate > current.nextDue
```

Comment: I didn't test this, just wrote it adhoc, so it might need to be tweaked a little.  Also, it's been a long time since I wrote MS Access SQL, my syntax might be a little off.

Comment: sweet. I was just looking over it, I haven't tried it yet; it doesn't look QUITE right. I'm actually at work right now, I'm going to sit down and use your theory to see if I can't figure it out, once my employees get off my back! lol thanks a ton.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to which are placeholders lol. The name of the record table is rec_completionDate

Comment: and actually just looking at the amount of joins here... access is really stupid about how to do these. They have to be nested. What a nightmare

Comment: the only placeholder I used in the final query text is "Table" which you would replace with rec_completionDate.

If it helps, write each subquery (the queries inside of the parentheses) as separate query objects in access.  Do you use the MS Access query designer?

Comment: No, i tend to do everything by hand. That sounds like a good idea though to avoid the rats nest. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Also, I just changed it a little bit.  Re-reading it there was one too many subqueries.

Comment: I hate the MS Access SQL editor because it destroys all of your line breaks, tabs, etc... and makes your code look like a mess.  You should be able to cut and paste the above into a query though and it should rock n roll.   Good luck!

Comment: I hate trying to figure out multiple joins in Access. The nesting is ridiculous. Here's what I got but it's saying i have an error in the join. Staring at it, it seems right. Not sure what I'm missing: SELECT current.*, next.*
FROM reportSubquery1 as sq 
INNER JOIN (rec_controlCompletion as current
INNER JOIN rec_controlCompletion as next ON sq.nextId = next.id) ON sq.currentId = current.id 
WHERE next.completedDate > current.nextDue